# Slither Tool Error - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: slither

I'm trying to use SLITHER (https://github.com/crytic/slither) but when i try to use it for specific contracts file its gives an error i.e. crytic_compile.platform.exceptions.InvalidCompilation: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

For Example: slither contracts/Helloworld.sol -- gives an above Error

FYI, slither . -- From main directory works well for Helloworld.sol
But want to execute for specific .sol file which gives an above error.
Using Widonws, tuffles and VS code.

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

Comment: The error is due to python having issues to locate files in windows. I had the same issue and could not solve it. The solution for me was to instal LSW (linux subsystem for windows) and run slitler from the terminal using ubuntu. It worked without issues there.